# DKIM fail using mailcow

Tags: dkim

I'm using Mailcow,
I can send email but it goes to spam folder in Gmail,
check header it says "DKIM fail".
spf and DMARC are passed.

I just copied dkim record from mailcow UI and pasted it into domain's DNS.

this is the DNS setings

```
DKIM._DOMAINKEY TXT  3600 v=DKIM1;k=rsa;t=s;s=email;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtltohTp1WvnqRlFkGbaG9Urchi6jnvAQTBRxiehh6ZcslrBdU9KfXVMFDckasKyeHP0tVZSTTWRAiroiTWfKLk7trq3DBsy+Wc8EAz6yMEVLwyCJhh1wtgC/khHjdxzrvQrxbbJIYnz79bKTMUp4/Cr6BJ7eRBnjxWuwJtDmbuGZaxLl5biPvgbUmXqQWGvncSIUrytmLvd2XzLETXDBueIezB0vjZxfFH65znYOs4J+y6hd+EryWjGlM1Gy4Y8uwaKJhVCwdrOGCQjRYeZW3OA1NDCyYxlkPi5mSK/WGIVZBwTdAKwrV5NP2HyNZ5HCZIC8VzcSKAJ3VYHeTsaesQIDAQAB
```

this is the header

DKIM FAILED

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=jpyy.ml; s=dkim;
    t=1671204384; h=from:subject:date:message-id:to:mime-version:content-type;
    bh=RenstW80cSPLXw/2g0G4x1MNFKyZVMXFRE1oZh7R63c=;
    b=FKL9WJIT6f2xgTQnGPgg6i2SaXyjbWtxTFnQAwcfceqPWKYtzrPJkebLmj8ZHDXGv3+7J5
    +XiRjtQOqF5q0KHhNy06fmx1j66n6Z//zTpWhVdVAqjwTeelqfPu2tewt8tZgpvN5Bqpvm
    9+jBJ0iw0Hd+IS/H6uy7TgRPVQzqJ9+bZW99SxDt5QJxTOxW1wsbmEv/4V8P47vARyQCd0
    adPenQewmS8f0BoJwS30pnwVjiHO3ZSe/huBSrlsvWbjjM6b5E+cIfUckBX5dNtiylmcNx
    YACE9Q/QYd/SmvyZnAxFDAFUkCeuKLMxFGKeBBxN6iecyThjVMajspgp1N6z4w==
Signed-by: mail@jjyy.ml
Expected-Body-Hash: RenstW80cSPLXw/2g0G4x1MNFKyZVMXFRE1oZh7R63c=
Public-Key: v=DKIM1;k=rsa;t=s;s=email;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArZGc4NCdvFe5WSXASt7bcsI0E5XrO97yaokMB65cLOi6RDfS4+N9Jt3MlFMKCEJTAa/BT6fHEDJpEOngI9U3Oz8SiTLvzFLz/quguLGZhNYVL1N7yHrMBEP4xsmD1zeoxF573ioIBHeil/27RCQitvco1xUAC5houoA0V3PuayS411Qmgqiinr93gBiaRvKnpGs82pbkQa9N5QDHwDzyTszMemSbEbC4CfBFu7SOlf8ziSVfS/F1VTY/rBa30uSQ8YDz4NbaecykbU4W/QwdHDA9kljUKrCbhA7nOds+l1l+fLl+mtgpu/dAMR9RJ4arNvRmAPv8IojV35Kdg+MH/wIDAQAB;

DKIM-Result: fail (bad signature)
```

I've been struggling with this for 2 days.
any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You have a `d=jpyy.ml` and a `Signed-by: mail@jjyy.ml` (`i=`?). Was this intentional? The RFC says that when using the `t=s` tag/flag in the Selector records, the domain part in the `i=` tag should match the domain in the `d=` tag in the signature. In your example it seems like it's not.